# What's the probability that a family with 5 children has 4 boys and 1 girl?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, conditional-probability

In this situation, the chances of having a boy/girl is NOT equally likely. The probability of having a boy is 0.55, so how does this knowledge change how I approach the problem>

I've tried it by doing (0.55)^4 * (0.45) / 32 to be a solution, but also 5C4/32 but both wield different answers. So, I'm not sure I understand how I'm supposed to get to the proper answer.

Comment: This is just a binomial distribution, and the standard formulas apply.

Comment: You can't divide by the number of cases unless each case is equally likely, which they're not, since boys are more frequent.  Add up the probabilities of all cases where the event happens.

Comment: With $P(B) = .55,$ you can't have denominator $2^5.$

Answer (score 2):

If $P(B)=0.55$, $P(G)=1-0.55=0.45$

$$P(4 \text{boys and} 1 \text{girl})=\binom{5}{4}\times (0.55)^4\times (0.45)^1$$

Comment: In R, where `dbinom` is binomial PDF, code `dbinom(4,5,.55)` returns $0.2058891,$ as does code `5*.55^4*.45`
>